# Sum all characters from the table and show sum as one SQL

Tags: sql

I have one table (Animals), one column (species) and three rows (1. bird, 2. dogs 3. cats). So total sum of characters is 12. How do I get the answer as 12 instead of 4, 4, 4?

I have tried different variations, but I just can't get this work. What code snippet I'm missing here?

```
SELECT LENGTH(Animals.species)
FROM Animals;
```

Comment: SELECT sum(LENGTH(species)) FROM Animals;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jsut do a sum of all

```
SELECT sum(LENGTH(Animals.species)) FROM Animals;
```